# Is there any log file created in windows for all the USB drive last plugged in and out

Tags: windows, usb-storage, event-log, device-manager, event-viewer

There's a professor of mine who's USB hard drive was stolen from her desk plugged into her laptop.

So I was wondering if there is any way or any "log file" in windows which stores the date and time of all USB drives last "plugged in/plugged out" so that I can find at what time exactly the hard drive was plugged out and stolen.

**Please tell me if it is even possible from "windows event viewer", "Device manager" or "Registry Editor" etc?**

I tried a software [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) from *Nirsoft* but it only showed the last time when the USB drive was plugged in.

Comment: You should leave the investigation to the school's IT department.  As a student its unlikely you will happen, you should not attempt to over extend your permissions, allow the people paid by the school to support this sort of thing perform the investigation.

Comment: I meant to say "As a student its unlikely you will actually help"

Comment: #Ramhound  you are right but the professor asked me for help, the problem is there's no camera inside the cabinet there's one in the gallery stills the entrance of the cabinet is in the blind spot we saw the footage there were so many students and staff came to that area, she can't questions every one, if we can find the exact time the number of  suspect will be narrowed down to 2 or 3.

Comment: You should still not exceed your authority.  If you have not been given the explicit permission to perform this invesigation by the school, you are likely slowing it down instead of helping it.  Being asked by the professor, who themselfs are unlikely to have that authority, does not count.